# Create custom post type when plugin is activated and remove once deactivated -Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want my plugin to create custom post type automatically when activated.

here's my code

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_myplugin');

function activate_myplugin() {

add_action('init', 'create_custom_type_post');

function create_custom_type_post() {

register_post_type('customposttype', array(
    'label' => 'my custom type post',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'mycustomposttype',
        'with_front' => false
        ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes'
        )
    )
);
}
```

}

and also how to remove it when deactivated??

Comment: what is the issue you are facing in this code?

Comment: when activated it's not creating CPT.

Comment: move outside your code add_action and

function create_custom_type_post() from activate_myplugin() function

Comment: didn't work, as i want CPT to be created as plugin is activated.

Comment: Add answer and its working so check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete code is below which is working for me.

```
       add_action( 'init', 'activate_myplugin' );
        function activate_myplugin() {


                $args=array(
            'label' => 'my custom type post',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'mycustomposttype',
                'with_front' => false
                ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'trackbacks',
                'custom-fields',
                'revisions',
                'thumbnail',
                'author',
                'page-attributes'
                )
            ); 
                register_post_type( 'customposttype', $args );

        }



        function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
                activate_myplugin();
                flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );

        register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_uninstall' );
        function my_plugin_uninstall() {
          // Uninstallation stuff here
             unregister_post_type( 'customposttype' );
        }
```

Comment: works! just make sure you add the first line as code.